# Are "thread-safe" functions parallelization framework dependent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, c++11, openmp

I have this simple MATLAB code which calls `imregionalmax` in a parallel loop 
over 256 pathces of 16X16 pixels.

```
function y = Parimregionalmax(x)
   assert(isa(x,'uint8'));
   assert( all(size(x)==[16 16 256]) );
   y = zeros(size(x));
   parfor k = 1:size(x,3)  
     y(:,:,k) = imregionalmax(x(:,:,k));
   end
end
```

Giving this code to MATLAB's Coder gives the following C code:

```
/*
 * Parimregionalmax.c
 *
 * Code generation for function 'Parimregionalmax'
 *
 */

/* Include files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "Parimregionalmax.h"
#include "libmwimregionalmax.h"

/* Function Definitions */
void Parimregionalmax(const unsigned char x[65536], double y[65536])
{
  int k;
  int i0;
  int i1;
  double imSize[2];
  unsigned char varargin_1[256];
  boolean_T conn[9];//unsigned char 
  double connSize[2];
  boolean_T BW[256];

#pragma omp parallel for \
 num_threads(omp_get_max_threads()) \
 private(i0,i1) \
 firstprivate(varargin_1,imSize,conn,connSize,BW)

  for (k = 0; k < 256; k++) {
    for (i0 = 0; i0 < 16; i0++) {
      for (i1 = 0; i1 < 16; i1++) {
        varargin_1[i1 + (i0 << 4)] = x[(i1 + (i0 << 4)) + (k << 8)];
      }
    }

    for (i0 = 0; i0 < 2; i0++) {
      imSize[i0] = 16.0;
    }

    for (i0 = 0; i0 < 9; i0++) {
      conn[i0] = true;
    }

    for (i0 = 0; i0 < 2; i0++) {
      connSize[i0] = 3.0;
    }

    imregionalmax_uint8(varargin_1, BW, 2.0, imSize, conn, 2.0, connSize);
    for (i0 = 0; i0 < 16; i0++) {
      for (i1 = 0; i1 < 16; i1++) {
        y[(i1 + (i0 << 4)) + (k << 8)] = BW[i1 + (i0 << 4)];
      }
    }
  }
}

/* End of code generation (Parimregionalmax.c) */
```

As you can see, the generated code (which works perfectly) uses openmp parallelization framework and calls the function `imregionalmax_uint8` which is implemented in a separate "black-box" dll (with corresponding header and lib files).

Can I assume that this fuction is always thread safe no matter which parallelization framework I use?

**Examples:**

1.Is it OK to define two threads using C++ `<thread>` library in a console 
  application (a.k.a exe file in VS) and call from  each thread to 
  `imregionalmax_uint8`?

2. Do two separate dlls (loaded by exe file) can call this function 
   simultaneously?

Comment: No, that function doesn't know beans about threading.  Just like almost any function it assumes that the caller will take care of thread-safety, ensuring that the region data cannot change while the function is executing.  Which the #pragma omp takes care of.  That the client programmer of a function is always responsible for thread-safety, usually the person least qualified to know the implications, is the basic reason why writing threaded code is difficult.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean by "ensuring that the region data cannot change while the function is executing"? how can I ensure that?

Comment: Don't let another thread write to it.  Which the #pragma omp takes care of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, because next to nobody writes out good guarantees for this kind of thing.  [This is a wonderful podcast about NVidia using C++'s threading model](http://cppcast.com/2017/09/olivier-giroux/) to finally formalize a threading system, with the complaint that prior to C++'s attempts most abstract threading/memory models out there where crap.  At best you'd get very arcane and specific information about a specific set of hardware, or claims that you worked like some other (usually more ancient) hardware.

Except yes, because in practice, the kinds of mutexes and synchronization and the like they are using are going to be compatible on pretty much every desktop system.  Maybe less so on mobile computing CPUs and other more obscure systems.